# How can I build a regex for a rewrite rule in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting

I'm currently trying to write a rewrite rule for a url in WordPress. The original URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost/download/d0RqYU8xek9JOXBsQmJrRGpldWF2QT09/?selected_files%5B0%5D=TURUWEdaWWNtS1ZOd2NSY0MybThCQT09&selected_files%5B1%5D=cWhFVEtlOENNM0VwNmlrUlBmOVF1UT09
```

The first value after the `/download/` is a unique identifier for a specific file store. After that I've added an array of files.

In WordPress I want to write now a rewrite URL for this request so that I can handle it in my backend. For that I need a specific regex that identifies the request and returns matches for building my rewrite url:

```
public function filter_rewrite_rules_array( $rules ): array {
    $new_rules['download/([0-9][a-z][A-Z]+)/.......'] = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) . '?download=$matches[1]&selected_files=$matches[2]';
    return array_merge( $rules, $new_rules );
}
```

The point is that I can't get the regex done.... can someone please help me with this? Even the first match don't works.

**Update:**

I'm expecting this URL in result:

```
http://localhost/admin-ajax.php?download=d0RqYU8xek9JOXBsQmJrRGpldWF2QT09&selected_files%5B0%5D=TURUWEdaWWNtS1ZOd2NSY0MybThCQT09&selected_files%5B1%5D=cWhFVEtlOENNM0VwNmlrUlBmOVF1UT09
```

As I just saw now - the request can have multiple file ids. So no idea how to get this done with a regex. Is this even possible?

Comment: Please add your expected result too.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Done!

Comment: This part is static: `http://localhost/admin-ajax.php?download=` the rest dynamic.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Yes! Thanks a lot. Please post it as answer so I can give you a checkmark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
.*?\/download\/(.*?)\/\?(.*)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`.*?`** - **Lazily** matches everything before `\download`.
>
> **`\/download\/`** - Matches `/download/` literally.
>
> **`(.*?)`** - Represents a capturing group matching the unique id which you require i.e. matches anything before `/?` **lazily**.
>
> **`(.*)`** - Represents the second capturing group matching the rest of the part of the url.
>
> **The replacement part:** Since the part `http://localhost/admin-ajax.php?download=` is static; you can use the use it along with the captured groups i.e. `http://localhost/admin-ajax.php?download=$1&$2`.

---

[image: Picotrial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/5hgR9d/2)